# Can't add files to bootable usb

Tags: boot, usb, filesystem, read-only

I created a bootable Lubuntu USB using a Ubuntu 16 machine using the startup disk creator tool in Ubuntu. the disk is created well. than i need to add a file to the folder EFI/BOOT

I need to add there the [32 bit bootloader](/questions/551320/ubuntu-on-asus-x205ta)
and try to use `sudo cp bootia.efi /media/user/Lubuntu 16.10 amd64/EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi` and get the following error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/media/user/Lubuntu 16.10 amd64/EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi': Read-only file system
```

Seems that the file system is read only, i changed the read only bit, as explained in the following link as explained [here](/questions/101637/usb-turn-write-protection-off)

And still get an error that says the drive is not writable. How can I make it writable?

Comment: Maybe the bootable USB drive has a read-only file system. How did your create it? Did you use a cloning tool, for example the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator? If you want to add files and even install program packages, I suggest that you create a persistent live drive, which is possible with mkusb. See these links, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent

Comment: It's unclear what you write, and where to. There is no actual command that leads to the error. What is read only? Note, actually writing the image to USB is the last step, but your first line says:"I created a bootable lubuntu usb using a Ubuntu 16 machine."

Comment: What's the output of `grep -Fe 'Lubuntu 16.10 amd64' /proc/mounts` and `sudo lsblk -f`?

Comment: the first one's output is nothing, the second gives the mount points of the partitions, the one that is relevant to the problematic file system is:

Comment: the first one gives nothing, maybe i need to add something to the command? the second one's part that is relevant to the problematic file system is: sdc    iso9660 Lubuntu 16.10 amd64
│                                2016-10-12-19-56-15-00               
├─sdc2 vfat    Lubuntu 16.10 amd64
│                                34F4-A3F4                            
└─sdc1 iso9660 Lubuntu 16.10 amd64
                                 2016-10-12-19-56-15-00

Comment: The iso9660 file system is read-only and I think the vfat partition is a small EFI partition. You cannot use those partitions to store data. I suggest that you create a persistent live drive according to my first comment. - Please explain why you need to att the 32 bit bootloader. What computer is it, and how do you want to use it?